# he conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005

I am executing below query but getting below error.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Calendar]  ([ID],[Year],[Quarter],[Week],[Stdate],[EdDate])
VALUES (680, 2020, 1, 1, convert(datetime,'30-06-2019 00:00:00 AM'), convert(datetime,'06-07-2019 23:59:00 PM'));
```

Error Message:

> The conversion of a char data type to a DateTime data type resulted in
>   an out-of-range DateTime value.

Comment: Just as a note: SQL Server 2005 has been **out of extended support** for quite a while now; urgent time to upgrade!

Answer (score 0):

Change the date from dd-MM format to MM-dd format in your query

```
convert(datetime,'06-30-2019 00:00:00 AM')
```

Comment: Or better yet : convert it to **ISO-8601** format: `20190630` - then it will work **regardless** of what your language/regional settings are!

Comment: I got my answer, It was out of range issue because in month field I was a passing year. it didn't accumulate 4 digits in 2 digit space.

Answer (score 0):

do not use Am PM :

select  convert(datetime,'06-07-2019 23:59:00')

Comment: I got my answer, It was out of range issue because in month field I was a passing year. it didn't accumulate 4 digits in 2 digit space.

Answer (score 0):

We can have different types of conversions:

- **Try Parse**

  It converts string datatype to a targetted datatype(Date or numeric)

Here is an example:

```
Declare @fakeDate as varchar(10);
Declare @realDate as varchar(10);
set @fakeDate = 'I am not a date';
set @realdate = '13/09/2015';

select try_parse (@fakeDate as DATE); --Null  because the parsing fails
select try_parse (@realDate as DATE); --Null due to type mismatch
select try_parse (@realDate as DATE using 'FR-FR'); --13/09/2015
```

- **Try Convert**

It converts value to a specified datatype, if conversion fails it returns NULL
The syntax is:

```
try_convert(data_type[(length)], expression[,style])
```

- **Convert**

It converts expressions from one type to another,
an example is:

```
select convert(varchar(20),GetDate,108);
```

Hope it may help you out.